# Why I am not able to install some packages in npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-watch

I'm using npm andI noticed that it's not always possible to install packages. For ex I'm able to instal jquery using regular npm command `npm install jquery` but I'm not able to install **webpack-watch-server** using command `npm i webpack-watch-server` besause of an error

`npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/homedir-polyfill failed, reason: read ECONNRESET`

What does it mean? Does some dependencies of the package which I want to install are not available anymore or should I reconfigure npm?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by installing dependencies with npm ERR! status manually:
first I install `homedir-polyfill` separately and then again `webpack-watch-server`